# JFreechart X and Y axis scaling

Tags: java, scale, jfreechart

It's possible to set the axis scale values in jfreechart?
For example, I'd want X-axis scale 10 and Y-Axis scale 1.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You set the `TickUnit`, if you are using an `XYPlot` try this

```
XYPlot plot = chart.getXYPlot();
NumberAxis xAxis = (NumberAxis) plot.getDomainAxis();
xAxis.setTickUnit(new NumberTickUnit(10));

NumberAxis yAxis = (NumberAxis) plot.getRangeAxis();
yAxis.setTickUnit(new NumberTickUnit(1));
```