# JFreeChart relative scaling

Tags: java, jfreechart

I want to create a Linegraph with JFreechart. My Data is like :

> Number1,Number2,Timestamp

So I want two Lines Where the Y-Axis is Number1 and Number2 and the X-Axis it the Timestamp.
I save the Chart as a png Image and the X-Axis looks just to long I think it is because of the timestamp beeing long apart. 
I Searched google and Stackoverflow but answers like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11306688/jfreechart-x-and-y-axis-scaling) dont work for me. How can i Fix this?

Here is my code:

```
         TimeSeries ts = new TimeSeries("Systole");

        ts.add(new Minute(new Date(1356999660000L)), 141);
        ts.add(new Minute(new Date(1356999840000L)), 129);
        ts.add(new Minute(new Date(1433074800000L)), 146);
        ts.add(new Minute(new Date(1433075700000L)), 136);

        TimeSeries diast = new TimeSeries("Diastole");

        diast.add(new Minute(new Date(1356999660000L)), 95);
        diast.add(new Minute(new Date(1356999840000L)), 86);
        diast.add(new Minute(new Date(1433074800000L)), 98);
        diast.add(new Minute(new Date(1433075700000L)), 91);
        final XYSeriesCollection dataset = new XYSeriesCollection();
        dataset.addSeries(systole);
        dataset.addSeries(diastole);
        XYDataset data = dataset;
  final TimeSeriesCollection dataset = new TimeSeriesCollection();
        dataset.addSeries(ts);
        dataset.addSeries(diast);
        XYDataset data = dataset;
        //String title, String timeAxisLabel, String valueAxisLabel, XYDataset dataset

        JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createTimeSeriesChart("Blutdruck", "", "", data);      
        SaveImage(chart.createBufferedImage(500,500),"Test1.png");
```

[image]

Comment: I assume the picture shows the current graph, but what would be the expected graph?

Comment: Looks like the expected result to me.

Comment: `ts.add(new Minute(new Date(1356999660000L)), 141); ts.add(new Minute(new Date(1356999840000L)), 129);` makes a vertical line but the is a difference in the Timestamp. On the Graph the look like at the were at the same time but they should have different times

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "vertical lines" effect happens because you are plotting a series that fluctuates on very different scales (minutes vs. years). Obviously, the variations at the scale of a minute are completely invisible when plotting them over a period of two years. It is like trying to draw the streets of a city on the map of a country.

There is no out-of-the-box solution for that problem, but you could find inspiration from the typical share price plots (from Google or Yahoo), where they let the user choose the scale they want to use.

**Variation over five days:**
[image]

**Variation over three months:**
[image]

Note that the variation over three months is **smoother** than the variation over five days. The reason is that they do not try to plot the value at every minute. Instead, they "subsample" their data.

In other words, they take the average over one day and plot only the values for each day.

Comment: The Data in my case is the Bloodpresure of a Patient measurent by the Doctor and stored in a database so it is important to have the timestamp to be very accurate

Comment: For sure, you should not alter the original data. Subsampling should be done only for the largest scale. It is optional anyway (it is a trick to make the graph look good and faster to plot).

Comment: To be clear, your vertical lines *should be* vertical, it's not a bug. However, if it is relevant for the users to see the variations of blood pressure at the scale of a minute, just give them the ability to "zoom in" on those vertical lines.

Comment: @Zion: Try `setAutoRangeIncludesZero(true)` to see the effect.